# How to calculate Running time of an algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I have the following algorithm below :

```
for(i = 1; i < n; i++){ 
   SmallPos = i;
   Smallest = Array[SmallPos]; 
   for(j = i + 1; j <= n; j++)
            if (Array[j] < Smallest) { 
                   SmallPos = j;
                   Smallest = Array[SmallPos];
                } 
   Array[SmallPos] = Array[i]; 
   Array[i] = Smallest;
}
```

Here is my calculation :

```
For the nested loop, I find a time complexity of
1 ("int i = 0") + n+1 ("i < n") + n ("i++")
* [1 ("j = i + 1") + n+1 ("j < n") + n ("j++")]
+ 3n (for the if-statement and the statements in it)
+ 4n (the 2 statements before the inner for-loop and the final 2 statements after the  inner for-loop). 
This is (1 + n + 1 + n)(1 + 1 + n + n) + 7n = (2 + 2n)(2 + 2n) + 7n = 4n^2 + 15n + 4.
```

But unfortunately, the text book got **T(n)  = 2n^2 +4n -5**.
Please, anyone care to explain to me where I got it wrong?

Comment: Are you counting lines of code executed?  Statements executed?

Comment: The book explains it clearly, please ask if you have specific doubts, I can help you.

Comment: I was asking why I can't still arrive at the answer the book got using my analysis given in my question? what did I do wrong?

Comment: Example 8 in the document you linked works that same example and shows exactly how the statements are counted. Can you not just check your analysis against that worked example?

Comment: Hello guys, I am trying to do it in a different way. I just needed to know why my own calculation was wrong.

Comment: Where is the exercise?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a formal manner to represent your algorithm, mathematically (Sigma Notation):

[image]

Replace **c** by the number of operations in the outer loop, and **c'** by the number of operations in the inner loop.